# Archimedean property of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

**Prop:** Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y$. Then, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $nx>y$.

Suppose for a contradiction, let $A$ be the set of all $nx$, where $n$ runs through the positive integers.  If (a) were false, then $y$ would be an upper bound of $A$.  But then $A$ has a *least* upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$.  Put $\alpha = \sup A$.  Since $x > 0$, $\alpha - x < \alpha$, and $\alpha - x$ is not an upper bound of $A$. $\alpha - x < mx$ for some positive integer $m$.  But then $\alpha < (m+1)x \in A$, which is impossible, since $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$$\square$.

The proof asserts that we can find a positive integer $m$ such that $\alpha-x<mx$. How is it possible?

Comment: Your proposition is false if $x \lt 0 $

Comment: "How is it possible?"  It isn't.  That's why it's a proof by contradiction.

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction.  They are assuming that $nx < y$ for all $n$.  So $1 < 2$.  And $2*1 < 2$ and $3*1 < 2$.  ANd $4*1 < 2$.  As this is clearly not true then $x = 1; y=2$ is not an example where the archemedian principal doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ is supposed to be an upper bound on $A$, all the integer multiples of $x$.  In fact, there is no such $\alpha$, which is what the proof shows.  If $x=1, A=\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\},$ which has no upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

The proof doesn't assume it is true for *ALL* $x,y$.  Just that there is *some* $x,y$ where $mx < y$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$.

If $x = 1$ and $y = 2$ then these are *not* the ones where $mx < y$ because $2\times 1 \not < 2$.  In fact if we we to try to find the $x$ and $y$ where $mx < y$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$ we would never by able to find them because (SPOILER ALERT) they don't exist.  For every $x,y: 0< x <y$ there is some $n \in \mathbb N$ where $nx > y$ so we can never find that $x,y$ were $mx < y$ for *all* $m$.

But this is a proof by contradiction.

If we take $x = 1$ and $y$ is some real number so that $m\cdot 1 < y$ for all $y$..... Is it possible that there exists such a $y$?  The answer should be an obvious no.  That would mean that $y$ is bigger than *EVERY* possible natural number!  And that's clearly absurd..... or is it.  *Why* can't there be a real number that is bigger than all natural numbers?  We can't just say that is absurd because is *seems* absurd.  We *must* disprove it.

And that is what the proof tries to do.  By contradiction.  And that's the important thing about a proof by contradiction.  We are assuming SOMETHING THAT IS NOT TRUE.

So if we assume that $m\cdot 1 < y$ for all $m$ then $y$ is an upper bound of the set $\{m\cdot 1|m\in \mathbb N\} = \mathbb N$.  (Note:  In reality, that is NOT TRUE. There is no such $y$ and there is no upper bound of $\mathbb N$.  But if there *were* such an $y$ then $y$ *would* be an upper bound of $\mathbb N$.  This is our first step to getting a contradictory false result.)

And if $\mathbb N$ is bounded above then there would be a $\sup \mathbb N$.  (Again, in reality this is NOT TRUE.  It is an incorrect result we are acheiving by assuming something false.)  Call the $\alpha = \sup \mathbb N$.  (In reality there is no such number as $\alpha$.)

Now for any number less than $\alpha$ then that number can not be an upper bound. (In reality that sentence makes no sense because there is no such number $\alpha$.)  And $1> 0$ so so $\alpha -1 < \alpha$.  So $\alpha -1$ is not an upper bound of $\mathbb N$.  So there is a natural number $m$ so that $\alpha - 1 < m$.  So $\alpha < m+1$.  But $m+1 \in \mathbb N$.

But $\alpha$ was the supremum of $\mathbb N$. (In reality, that was WRONG.) So $\alpha < m+1$ is impossible but we proved it.  So our assumption that there is a $y > m\cdot 1$  for all $m\in \mathbb N$ must have been wrong.  (As I've been telling you all along in these parenthesis.)

So there *is* an $m$ so that $m > y$ for any possible $y$. And $\alpha = \sup \{m\times 1\}$ DOES NOT EXIST.

.......

And the proof for any $x>0$ is the same type of argument.

....

So let's look at your question.

> The proof asserts that we can find a positive integer m such that $α−x < mx$.

No, the proof shows that $\alpha$ doesn't exit.

> Let's consider x=1,y=2, for example. Then, 1<2 and 2−1 is not an upper bound.

But ***IF*** we assume that for every $mx < y$ (which, in reality , IS NOT TRUE) then $2\cdot 1 < 2$ and $3\cdot 1 < 2$ etc..... but ..... $2\cdot 1 = 2$ and $2 \not < 2$.  So.... this is a contradiction.

There is no upper bound and we can never reach it (it doesn't exist).  If there were an upper bound and we reached it.... we'd be able to go beyond it.